# Nested v-tabs: Conditionally render the child tabs in order to show slider

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, conditional-rendering

I use nested tabs and have problems displaying active tabs.

As described in this [bug report](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/5182), the tab slider of the nested tabs is only displayed after you have clicked on it.

Conditional rendering is suggested as a solution. I have already tried some solutions, but I don't get a working result.

Reproduction Link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/xr7q9zl1qo

I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Conditional rendering must be done on the basis of the parent. The v-tabs v-model of the parent tab must be compared to the index from the v-for loop of the v-tab-item of the parent.

In this case:

```
v-if="activeClass === index"
```

Example:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
<v-tabs v-model="activeClass" slider-color="blue">
  <v-tab v-for="n in classTypes" :key="n.id" ripple>{{ n.text }}</v-tab>
  <v-tab-item v-for="(n, index) in classTypes" :key="n.id">
    <v-tabs v-model="activeTab[index]" slider-color="blue" v-if="activeClass === index">
      <v-tab>First child</v-tab>
      <v-tab>Second child</v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
  </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 name: "App",
 data() {
  return {
    classTypes: [{ id: 1, text: "First" }, { id: 2, text: "Second" }],
    activeClass: "1",
    activeTab: []
  };
 }
};
</script>
```

Reproduction link: https://codesandbox.io/s/lykynjn6vm